# How to freeze columns on both side of angular material data table?

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I'm using [md-data-table](https://github.com/daniel-nagy/md-data-table) where i have achieved fixed headers but somehow fixed columns is not working in my favor. Can someone please help me as i'm almost dead of searching an appropriate solution where both the functionalities will work.

Below is the link which i'm refering for my development.
[http://danielnagy.me/md-data-table/](https://github.com/daniel-nagy/md-data-table)

Answer (score 0):

Make a separate table that contains the data you want fixed. and align it with your other table. I’ve done the same in one of my projects and it works just fine.

A few issues are are raised on the github project you mentioned concerning fixed columns and there are a few workarounds you can attempt there if you want.

https://github.com/daniel-nagy/md-data-table/issues/311

https://github.com/daniel-nagy/md-data-table/issues/396

Comment: I have already tried most of the solution but none of them is working for me as i wanted to use both fix header and fix columns in md-data-table. Something like in this link 
https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedcolumns/examples/initialisation/left_right_columns.html

Comment: That seems like a good solution in your link. Any reason you can’t use that?